# How do I query Tasks from CURL

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to query tasks assigned to a user using CURL. For incidents I do

```
curl -L --user user:pass --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type:application/json" "https://endpoint.service-now.com/incident.do?JSONv2&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=assigned_to=<userid>
```

How do I do the same for Tasks assigned to a user ?

Comment: What kind of tasks do you wish to retrieve? Change Tasks? Catalog Tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try querying the Task table. Replace `incident.do` in your url with `task.do`